# Android Studio + Genymotion: App crashes when loading images

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I've been trying to create a very simple app, and for that, I'm making use of activity_main.xml only (currently). Whenever I place ImageView, app crashes. Without ImageView, it runs perfectly. Here's my code with ImageView set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="32">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Rock Paper Scissor"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/iconLayout"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rock"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/paper"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/scissor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/scoreID"
            android:text="Your Score: 0"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Computer Score: 0"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I remove the android:src from all 3 and then run, app runs fine. But with it, it crashes. Here's my logcat as well:

```
5.853 2171-2171/com.codedamn.m.firstapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2171 SIG: 9
05-29 10:23:44.459 3861-3861/com.codedamn.m.firstapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 95MB allocation
05-29 10:23:44.463 3861-3861/com.codedamn.m.firstapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 100000012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 62MB until OOM"
05-29 10:23:44.463 3861-3861/com.codedamn.m.firstapp D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-29 10:23:44.464 3861-3861/com.codedamn.m.firstapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-29 10:23:44.464 3861-3861/com.codedamn.m.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.codedamn.m.firstapp, PID: 3861
                                                                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 100000012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 62MB until OOM
                                                                           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at com.codedamn.m.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-29 10:24:44.974 3861-3861/com.codedamn.m.firstapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3861 SIG: 9
05-29 10:27:41.400 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp W/art: Verification of void android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.reportLoaderStart() took 176.439ms
05-29 10:27:41.451 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-29 10:27:42.040 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 95MB allocation
05-29 10:27:42.044 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 100000012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 62MB until OOM"
05-29 10:27:42.044 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-29 10:27:42.045 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-29 10:27:42.045 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.codedamn.m.firstapp, PID: 5851
                                                                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 100000012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 62MB until OOM
                                                                           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1039)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at com.codedamn.m.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-29 10:31:26.106 5851-5851/com.codedamn.m.firstapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5851 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is in your logcat?

Comment: You got out of memory. Depends of the size of your images and what exactly you are doing with them in Activity

Comment: I figured it out. I've 3 images, 2 are about ~60 kb each. The other one is ~ 800 kb. When I exclude the 800 kb one from the code, it runs. How much memory is allocated per app? @Leo

Comment: 800 kb should be ok.

Comment: Are you doing something with the ImageViews in activty?

Comment: Also your layout is not very efficient with nested weights. At least make layout_height = 0dp for nested layouts where you use weight

Comment: @Leo I've just started with Blank Activity -> and then the code that is above is in activity_main.xml. Nothing else.

Comment: try to use   android:layout_height="0dp" instead of   android:layout_height="wrap_content" everywhere you use android:layout_weight

Comment: Okay @Leo. Thank you for suggesting that. I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the images you are loading are pretty huge, because you are experiencing out of memory errors.

Try it with smaller images and see if that helps. Read the android developer site to deal with these issues.

Comment: I figured it out. I've 3 images, 2 are about ~60 kb each. The other one is ~ 800 kb. When I exclude the 800 kb one from the code, it runs. How much memory is allocated per app?

Comment: Nevermind, I compressed all images to about ~ 600 KB and now it works.